# error iis ejecutar psexec aplicacion asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Tengo una aplicacion hecha en webforms la cual debe ejecutar un proceso en otro servidor windows, para lo cual uso la aplicacion PsExec.

En el equipo de desarrollo funciona sin ningun problema (iis expres de visual studio), pero al poner en produccion la aplicacion no se ejecuta (IIS)

```
 private string resultado;

    

    protected string EjecutarETL(string argumentos)
    {
        using (Process bat = new Process())
        {
            string toolsDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bins");

            bat.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            bat.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            bat.StartInfo.FileName = toolsDir + "/PsExec.exe ";
            bat.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentos;
            bat.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            bat.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            bat.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
            bat.ErrorDataReceived += OnErrorDataReceived;
            bat.Start();
            bat.BeginOutputReadLine();
            bat.WaitForExit();
        }
        return resultado;


    }
    protected void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            resultado = e.Data.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }

    protected void OnErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            resultado = e.Data.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }

    protected void btnETL1_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        lblRes1.Text = EjecutarETL(@" \\XX.XX.XX.XX -u XXXXXX -p XXXXXXX -e I:\Bats_Pruebas\ETL_Primera_Malla.bat " + TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: tienes que anteponer -s -d antes del server o IP